# How to control the height of the parent box to apply transition?

Tags: css

I would like you to support me by guiding me with the possible solution to the following problem:

I require that the video when I scroll-And the video goes from 0% to 100% as the scroll is made, my problem is that when I do it the parent box is made to the size of the video, completely disappearing the content, here the example:

```js
function scrollShowPic() {

  const elementPic = document.getElementById("animationVideo")

  document.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
    if (scrollY <= "300") {
      elementPic.style.width = "0%"

    }
    if (scrollY >= "400") {
      elementPic.style.width = "10%"
    }

    if (scrollY >= "500") {
      elementPic.style.width = "20%"
    }

    if (scrollY >= "600") {
      elementPic.style.width = "30%"
    }

    if (scrollY >= "700") {
      elementPic.style.width = "50%"
    }

    if (scrollY >= "800") {
      elementPic.style.width = "70%"
    }

    if (scrollY >= "900") {
      elementPic.style.width = "80%"
    }

    if (scrollY >= "1000") {
      elementPic.style.width = "90%"
    }

    if (scrollY >= "1100") {
      elementPic.style.width = "100%"
    }





  })


}

scrollShowPic()
```

```css
.about-us {
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  border: 5px solid;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  border-top-right-radius: 88px;
}

.video {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dudas y prácticas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat
    consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam
    obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed
    commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis
    molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet
    at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum!
    Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem
    ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem
    earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis
    porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae
    officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat
    mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium
    quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam,
    maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque
    cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus
    aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam.
    Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum
    expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias
    ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore,
    nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae
    voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus
    alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam
    aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae
    vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente
    quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt
    ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae
    hic sed commodi ducimus
  </p>
  <section class="about-us">

    <div class="center">

      <div class="video">
        <video id="animationVideo" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" class="swipeleft" style="clip-path: polygon(0% 0px, 100% 0px, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);">
          <source src="https://dev.jankelley.com/app/uploads/2022/01/JK_Homepage_2_675 x 546-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="https://dev.jankelley.com/app/uploads/2022/01/JK_Homepage_2_675 x 546.ogv" type="video/webm">
          <source src="https://dev.jankelley.com/app/uploads/2022/01/JK_Homepage_2_675 x 546.webm" type="video/ogv">
          Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat
    consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam
    obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed
    commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis
    molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet
    at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum!
    Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem
    ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem
    earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis
    porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae
    officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat
    mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium
    quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam,
    maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque
    cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus
    aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam.
    Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum
    expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias
    ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore,
    nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae
    voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus
    alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam
    aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae
    vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente
    quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt
    ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae
    hic sed commodi ducimus
  </section>

  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I wanted to place the father with a certain height but at the high resolution, I don't like how it looks so I have to find a solution on how to make the video not have that behavior I really hope you can guide me thank you very much.

here I leave the page that I want to clone   [enter link description here](https://jankelley.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, they are using `polygon` instead of `width`, and check the element in view instead of scroll position

```js
function getViewPercentage(element) {
  const viewport = {
top: window.pageYOffset,
bottom: window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight
  };

  const elementBoundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const elementPos = {
top: elementBoundingRect.y + window.pageYOffset,
bottom: elementBoundingRect.y + elementBoundingRect.height + window.pageYOffset
  };

  if (viewport.top > elementPos.bottom || viewport.bottom < elementPos.top) {
return 0;
  }

  // Element is fully within viewport
  if (viewport.top < elementPos.top && viewport.bottom > elementPos.bottom) {
return 100;
  }

  // Element is bigger than the viewport
  if (elementPos.top < viewport.top && elementPos.bottom > viewport.bottom) {
return 100;
  }

  const elementHeight = elementBoundingRect.height;
  let elementHeightInView = elementHeight;

  if (elementPos.top < viewport.top) {
elementHeightInView = elementHeight - (window.pageYOffset - elementPos.top);
  }

  if (elementPos.bottom > viewport.bottom) {
elementHeightInView = elementHeightInView - (elementPos.bottom - viewport.bottom);
  }

  const percentageInView = (elementHeightInView / window.innerHeight) * 100;

  return Math.round(percentageInView);
}

function scrollShowPic(){
   const elementPic= document.getElementById("animationVideo")
 document.addEventListener("scroll", e=>{
 
 const percent = getViewPercentage(elementPic)
 const polygonPercent = 100 - percent > 0 ? 100 - percent : 0
 
 console.log(polygonPercent)
  
  elementPic.style.clipPath= `polygon(${polygonPercent}% 0px, 100% 0px, 100% 100%, ${polygonPercent}% 100%)`
 
 })
   

   }

   scrollShowPic()
```

```css
.about-us {
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  border: 5px solid;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  border-top-right-radius: 88px;
}

.video {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dudas y prácticas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat
    consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam
    obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed
    commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis
    molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet
    at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum!
    Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem
    ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem
    earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis
    porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae
    officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat
    mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium
    quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam,
    maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque
    cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus
    aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam.
    Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum
    expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias
    ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore,
    nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae
    voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus
    alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam
    aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae
    vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente
    quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt
    ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae
    hic sed commodi ducimus
  </p>
  <section class="about-us">

    <div class="center">

      <div class="video">
        <video id="animationVideo" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" class="swipeleft" style="clip-path: polygon(0% 0px, 100% 0px, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);">
          <source src="https://dev.jankelley.com/app/uploads/2022/01/JK_Homepage_2_675 x 546-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="https://dev.jankelley.com/app/uploads/2022/01/JK_Homepage_2_675 x 546.ogv" type="video/webm">
          <source src="https://dev.jankelley.com/app/uploads/2022/01/JK_Homepage_2_675 x 546.webm" type="video/ogv">
          Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat
    consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam
    obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed
    commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis
    molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet
    at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis porro cumque saepe laborum!
    Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, nihil nam. Assumenda animi voluptatibus numquam, maiores at a quo est, repudiandae officiis maxime exercitationem
    ad voluptates reiciendis, facilis molestiae id placeat sapiente quaerat consequuntur ab. Tempora ipsum ipsam aliquid vitae dolor repudiandae voluptatum expedita asperiores illo, eaque cupiditate exercitationem qui quaerat mollitia! Ipsa dolor dolorem
    earum, nesciunt, fuga iusto amet at reiciendis architecto incidunt ullam obcaecati dolorum veritatis quae vero numquam magni, voluptas temporibus alias ipsam a quidem inventore! Temporibus aspernatur repudiandae praesentium quam consequuntur blanditiis
    porro cumque saepe laborum! Impedit eaque debitis recusandae hic sed commodi ducimus voluptates suscipit.
  </section>

  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```